# MySQL query optimization and/or tweaks

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have the following query which both tables are huge. The query were very slow and I need your idea to optimize this query or do you have any other solution?

```
SELECT c.EstablishmentID,
   (SELECT COUNT(ID) 
    FROM cleanpoi 
    WHERE EstablishmentID=c.EstablishmentID OR EstablishmentID 
    IN (SELECT ChildEstablishmentID 
        FROM crawlerchildren 
        WHERE ParentEstablishmentID=c.EstablishmentID)
    ) POI 
FROM crawler c 
GROUP BY c.EstablishmentID
```

BTW, I have the appropriate indexes applied.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I have attached the explain result.[image]

Comment: Try running the query with EXPLAIN in front and post the query plan

Comment: @Jords I have attached the explain result.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by using `JOIN`

```
SELECT  c.EstablishmentID, COUNT(d.ID)
FROM    crawler c
        LEFT JOIN cleanpoi d
            ON c.establishmentid = d.establishmentID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ChildEstablishmentID
            FROM crawlerchildren
        ) e ON e.ParentEstablishmentID = c.EstablishmentID
GROUP BY c.EstablishmentID
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it gives out an incorrect number. I'll try to check this query out.

Comment: try removing the subquery which has `DISTINCT`. instead of `LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ChildEstablishmentID
            FROM crawlerchildren
        )`, directly `LEFT JOIN crawlerchildren e ON e.ParentEstablishmentID = c.EstablishmentID`

Answer (score 0):

**IN() and NOT IN() subqueries are poorly optimized:**

MySQL executes the subquery as a dependent subquery for each row in the outer query. This is a frequent cause of serious performance problems in MySQL 5.5 and older versions. The query probably should be rewritten as a JOIN or a LEFT OUTER JOIN, respectively.

**Non-deterministic GROUP BY:**
The SQL retrieves columns that are neither in an aggregate function nor the GROUP BY expression, so these values will be non-deterministic in the result.

**GROUP BY or ORDER BY on different tables:**

This will force the use of a temporary table and filesort, which can be a huge performance problem and can consume large amounts of memory and temporary space on disk.

Comment: Actually, I did not ask for a theory. I ask for an option or any idea how to solve my problem.